# Can't deploy a custom web part

Tags: 2007, web-part, solution-deployment

I'm having problems deploying a web part in Sharepoint 2007.

I have the following setup:  One WFE, one server where I run and develop SSIS and web part solutions that also has sharepoint installed (I think this qualifies as a WFE), and a separate database server.  I recently upgraded to x64 and SharePoint has been running fine for a few months.  This is the first time I've tried to deploy a custom web part in the new environment.  It used to work like a charm but I've had nothing but problems with this attempt.

A few pertinent facts:

- SharePoint version on both the WFEs: 12.0.0.6421
- I know the code works because I copied it from a working existing web part (will change it later once I get this figured out)
- I think this probably has something to do with the fact that my web part development now lives on the d: drive instead of the c: drive but I can't figure out where the problem is occurring.

Here is what is going wrong:  After I build the solution (anycpu), copy the dll to the GAC  and run WSPbuilder.exe, I attempt to run the setup.exe from SharePoint Solution Installer. (downloaded from www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller).  On the system check screen, when the installer gets to the final step: "Checking features as specified in Config."  It fails with and error: "New Features specified: 1" I can't find anything on google about what this error means.

Here is my setup.exe.config file for the Sharepoint installer:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="BannerImage" value="Default"/>
    <add key="LogoImage" value="None"/>
    <add key="EULA" value=""/>
    <add key="Require" value="MOSS"/>
    <add key="MinSharePointVersion" value="12.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="MaxSharePointVersion" value=""/>
    <add key="SolutionId" value="172AC3A2-5D5E-44c0-B8CD-572300CC5789"/>
     <!-- FarmFeatureId: Old way to specify a single farm-level feature
        obsoleted by newer FeatureId key -->
     <add key="FarmFeatureId" value="172AC3A2-5D5E-44c0-B8CD-572300CC5789"/>
     <!-- FeatureId: Feature(s) to install/upgrade/repair
        Either a single GUID, or a semicolon delimited GUID list -->
    <add key="FeatureId" value="CB599E4E-6EA8-485E-A3F7-5430118BADB1"/>
     <!-- FeatureScope: Scope of feature(s) specified in FeatureId
      Legal values: Farm, Web Application, Site, Web-->
    <add key="FeatureScope" value="Site"/>
    <add key="SolutionFile" value="ProgWebPart_try3.wsp"/>
    <add key="SolutionTitle" value="Program Web Part Try 3"/>
    <!-- SolutionVersion: Version of solution: this value is stored in the farm property bag -->
    <add key="SolutionVersion" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="UpgradeDescription" value="Upgrades Program Web Part on all frontend web servers in the SharePoint farm."/>
    <add key="RequireDeploymentToCentralAdminWebApplication" value="true"/>
    <add key="RequireDeploymentToAllContentWebApplications" value="false"/>
    <!-- DefaultDeployToSRP: Whether box for Shared Resource Provider web app is initially checked
        if user is prompted for web applications to target -->
    <add key="DefaultDeployToSRP" value="false"/>
    <add key="DefaultDeployToAdminWebApplications" value="false"/>
    <add key="DefaultDeployToContentWebApplications" value="false"/>
    <!-- PromptForWebApplications: To force user prompt for web application; 
       useful if a dll is included, so SafeControl entries needed, 
       but feature not at webapp level -->
    <add key="PromptForWebApplications" value="false"/>
    </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Here is the feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Id="CB599E4E-6EA8-485e-A3F7-5430118BADB1" Title="Program Page Feature 3" Description="Deploys the Program Page Web Part." Scope="Site">
<ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="webpartsmanifest.xml" />
</ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Here is the webpartmanifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
     <Module Name="WebParts" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
       <File Url="ProgWebPart_try3.ProgWP.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
         <Property Name="Group" Value="RMI Web Parts" />
       </File>
    </Module>
    </Elements>
```

Here is the webpart file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <webParts>
    <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
    <type name="ProgWebPart_try3.ProgWP, ProgWebPart_try3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8778f1e462c36fd7" />
    <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this web part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
    <properties>
    <property name="Title" type="string">Program Web Part try 3</property>
    <property name="Description" type="string">Displays Program Information based on a query string.</property>
    </properties>
    </data>
    </webPart>
    </webParts>
```

I have the following line in the web.config (The PublicKeyToken for the dll in the GAC matches the one in the web.config):

```
    <SafeControl Assembly="ProgWebPart_try3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8778f1e462c36fd7" Namespace="ProgWebPart_try3" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

Does anyone have any thoughts about how I might resolve this?  Thanks